# JQuery SVG: stroke-linejoin: round

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I'm trying to get stroke lines to have rounded joins. Why isn't the code below working?

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6U6Q/1/).

```
$('body').svg({onLoad: function(svg){
    var path = svg.createPath();
    svg.path(
        path.move( 50, 50 )
        .line( 300, 0, true )
        .line( 0, 300, true )
        .line( -300, 0, true )
        .close(),
        {
            fill: 'none', 
            stroke: '#888', 
            strokeWidth: 30,
            strokeLinejoin: 'round'
        }
    );  
}});
```

According to [this OReilly documentation](http://oreilly.com/catalog/svgess/chapter/ch03.html), the style property and value I need is `stroke-linejoin` and `round`. And according to the JQuery-SVG documentation:

> Additional settings that contain a dash (-) in SVG should be written
>   in camel-case without the dash

So I can't see why it's not working.

Thanks

Update: I've [forked the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fpnq6/) , it seems when outputting the SVG XML, it has not converted the camel-case property to one with a dash. Now just to work out how to have it correct that. The SVG XML it's outputting is:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="400" height="400">
    <path d="M50,50l300,0l0,300l-300,0z" fill="none" stroke="#888" stroke-width="30"
         strokeLinejoin="round"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change:

```
strokeLinejoin: 'round'
```

to:

```
strokeLineJoin: 'round'
```